# How to cut a door wrapped in sheet metal

Tags: doors, drill, hardwood-refinishing, metal-cutting

In my kitchen I have a dumb waiter; the door is 1" thick solid wood wrapped in 1/16" sheet metal. I removed the old door knob (that's the hole in the photo) to make room for a flush pull. I need to cut the sheet metal in the shape of the pull to make it fit, but I'm not sure how to do this. I can't use clippers and I don't own a router; I have a Dremel and power drill only. I could drill holes along the cut out line using the power drill, but there's gotta be a better way.

[image]

Comment: I would take it to a fabrication shop that has a plasma cutter.

Comment: Is there an alternative option? emphasis "diy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Dremel tool with a cutoff wheel will be about as good as it gets for this application.

Scoring the line (not too deeply) with a cold chisel should help make a channel for the wheel to follow.

I'd tape up the rest of the surface before you start, so you don't have sparks and dirt marring the finish.

Comment: A dremel with a cut off tool will work great it may take quite a few disks , and be sure to wear safety glasses but of the tools you have it can do the job.+

Comment: Yep, that's how I'm doing it; I'll post an update next week!

Answer (score 0):

Best for you to  draw a inside and outside max liwas of the part  it looks like u have  a  have play room about half  to three quarter of inch I  material fabercater years ago Gininder and meatal file don't think that a dremel will  do it but maybe u would have to drill a bunch  of little holes inside lines first then jig saw meatal blade then grind with  dremel I have a dremel roto zip it would do it all itself I recommend every on should have one be careful it's a monster

Comment: I'm trying the Dremel route first